# C++ upper_bound on struct vector with == operator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have following struct,

```
struct cube
{
    int  index l , b , h;
    bool operator<(const cube & c2) const
    {
        if (l == c2.l && b == c2.b && h == c2.h)
            return index < c2.index;
        if (l == c2.l && b == c2.b)
            return h < c2.h;
        if (l == c2.l )
            return b < c2.b;
        return l < c2.l;
    }
    bool operator==(const cube  c2) 
    {
        return index != c2.index && l == c2.l && b == c2.b;
    }
};
```

Now I want to apply upper_bound on vector of this struct as per condition in == operator. 

However , it is still returning me those iterators where index are same

```
int pos2 = upper_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),v[i]) - v.begin();
```

i.e v[i].index is equal to v[pos2].index

Comment: `uppoer_bound` aside `index != c2.index` - does this mean that structs are equal if their indices are different?

Comment: no , I am only using `==` for upper_bound , there is no other use of `==` operator in my code

Comment: But `upper_bound` uses `operator<`, not `==`...

Comment: so how can I modify it so that I get only those positions where index is not equal to v[i].index

Comment: In order for your two operators to be logically consistent, I'd start by defining `==` in terms of `<` via `return !(*this < c2) && !(c2 < *this);`.

Comment: lets start from basics - is your vector `v` at least partitioned or even better - sorted with respect to your `operator <`? This is the requirement on the collection passed via iterator parameters to `std::upper_bound`

Comment: Ps. Have in mind that I wouldn't have to ask such a basic question if you would provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that for two `cube` instances `foo` and `bar` that `foo < bar` is `true` when `foo == bar` is also `true`. You could fix that by writing `index == c2.index && l == c2.l && b == c2.b` as the returned expression in `operator==`.

This contradiction is the root cause of your issues, although note that `std::upper_bound` does itself only require that `operator<` is implemented appropriately; which yours is.

Isn't `index` more of a property of a *collection* of `cube`s rather than a given `cube`? That is, it shouldn't appear in the `cube` class?

Comment: index is same for 6 cubes and all of theese 6 cubes are there in vector